# Apache Camel - Validate file length of downloaded file against file length from camel headers

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am trying to create a route setup which :

- Downloads a file from remote location into a "temporary/staging" folder
- Runs validation (processor) on the file, checking downloaded file has correct length according to Camel header
- If downloaded file length is correct

  - File is copied to destination directory
  - File key is added to idempotent repository
- If downloaded file length is not correct

  - Fail the route
  - Send email about issue
  - Do not add file key to idempotent repository
  - Retry downloading the file X times

So far I've come up with the following which doesn't quite work, for example I don't know how to prevent the file from being recorded as retrieved in the idempotent repo...

Is this on the right track? :

```
//Copy to staging as temp file
from(routeConfig.getFrom() + getCommonEndpointSettings())
        .routeId(routeConfig.getRouteId())
        // Grab the correct length of the remote file
        .setHeader(ORIGINAL_FILE_LENGTH, header(Exchange.FILE_LENGTH));

        // Exclude all files oder than the specified number of hours
        .filter(new FileModifiedSincePredicate(24))
        //Copy to staging folder for validation
        .to(routeConfig.getTo()+STAGING_FOLDER_NAME+"?fileName=${file:name}.temp")

        // Check the file size, throws exception if file size doesn't match
        .process(new FileSizeValidationProcessor() )
        // If we get here all is good and we can strip off the .temp file ending so the below route picks up the file
        .process(exchange -> {
             final String createdFileName = exchange.getIn().getHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME_PRODUCED, String.class);
             final File createdFile = new File(createdFileName);
             log.info("Removing .temp file ending from " + createdFile.getAbsolutePath());
             createdFile.renameTo(new File(createdFile.getAbsolutePath().replace(".temp", "")));
         });


// Copy non .temp files from staging folder to destination folder        
from(routeConfig.getTo()+STAGING_FOLDER_NAME+"?delete=true&delay=30s&antExclude=*.temp")
        .routeId("Copy Staging " +routeConfig.getRouteId())
        .to(routeConfig.getTo())
        .end();
```

Comment: Sorry, but where in your code are you moving it to the idempotent folder which is failing now?

Comment: The idempotent repo is setup in the string returned by `routeConfig.getFrom()` , simply something like `&idempotentRepository=#dempotentRepo` which is a Spring bean

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what is not working and what is your expected result?

Comment: In the above example the "file key" is record in the idempotent repository for  the route which means the route doesn't retry the download. I think that what I posted above is very clunky and I think there is probably a nicer solution. My expected result is in the question itself : )

Comment: I am still not quit following with your expected outcome. It would be great if you could post any errors or stack trace to clarify. Also, is the issue with the message proceeding beyond where you expect or some other logic? If you can clarify further that would be helpful.